# How to get latest build tool installed (locally) in android sdk using command line

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

Actually I am trying to get latest build tool installed in my machine. 
But here I don't want to go through my file system, I am looking for Android SDK commands to figure out latest build tool installed in my system.

Answer (score 1):

Not the prettiest or more stable trick but you can get the latest installed build tools by doing:

```
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --list | grep "build-tools/" | awk '{ print $3 }' | tail -1
```

Comment: Yes, it might work for non windows users, but I think it should be part of SDK itself. Thanks for the answer.